# How to convert BufferedImage to a MultiPart file without saving file to disk?

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, bufferedimage, resttemplate

I want to make a service call that takes in the following Request Parameter in a rest service.  This method uploads file to an image server.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
```

Following is the code where the call to the service is being made - I read an image in a BufferedImage object from a image url

```
     BufferedImage subImage= ImageIO.read(new URL(<some image url goes here>));
     File outputFile = new File("C:\\" + "myimage" + ".jpg");

    ImageIO.write(subImage, "jpg", outputFile);

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    String url="http://serviceurl/upload";

    body.add("file", outputFile);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(body, headers);

    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

AS you can see, a file is first being created and saved to the disk. How can I avoid this step and just use BufferedImage object (I do not want to save the file to the local disk).

Tried the solution below but it seems to me that you cannot achieve this without saving file on your disk. Is that true?

Comment: Is the MultipartFile is from `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it in this way.. I have created an implementation class of `MultipartFile` and I am  using that newly created class to create a `MultipartFile` file.

**MultipartFile Implementation**

```
public class MultipartImage implements MultipartFile {


private byte[] bytes;
String name;
String originalFilename;
String contentType;
boolean isEmpty;
long size;

public MultipartImage(byte[] bytes, String name, String originalFilename, String contentType,
        long size) {
    this.bytes = bytes;
    this.name = name;
    this.originalFilename = originalFilename;
    this.contentType = contentType;
    this.size = size;
    this.isEmpty = false;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public String getOriginalFilename() {
    return originalFilename;
}

@Override
public String getContentType() {
    return contentType;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return isEmpty;
}

@Override
public long getSize() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public byte[] getBytes() throws IOException {
    return bytes;
}

@Override
public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void transferTo(File dest) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Converting Jpg to `MultipartFile`

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("path to file"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( originalImage, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();

MultipartFile multipartFile = new MultipartImage(baos.toByteArray());
```

**OR**

if you dont want to create an implementation of MultipartFile class your own you can use `org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile` from spring

*Example:*

```
 MultipartFile multipartFile = MockMultipartFile(fileName, baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: I guess the flush should happen after the multipartFile object is created

Comment: Actually after thoroughly testing, this does not seem to be working. I get a 400 bad request error

Comment: I don't think the service above it getting invoked with this code.

Comment: Ok, will try that. Should this method be overridden as well - transferTo

Comment: MultipartFile multipartFile = new MultiPartImage(baos.toByteArray(), imageName+".jpg", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.toString(), baos.size());

Comment: The comment above - this is what I am setting in the constructor for all those variables you mentioned.

Comment: Cannot find this particular class in the package, it looks like it might be deprecated

Comment: <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>

Comment: While it helped, there is no way I can avoid saving the file on my local machine before sending it to another server. I was not able to avoid that. But I am doing a delete operation on the local machine to ensure that files do not get piled up.

Comment: MultipartFile multipartFile = new MultiPartImage(baos.toByteArray(), imageName+".jpg", imageName, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.toString(), baos.size());

Comment: Missing 1 property @Tisha

Answer (score 2):

Jobin Joseph, your class MultipartImage was a good starting point but in my case it wasn't work. I needed that class to resend programatically an image from Database to a Post service and it wasn't working because the service was expecting other fields and fields names (and a Serializable object too). I leave here your class modified to be used as a regular MultipartFile implementation:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class MultipartImage implements MultipartFile, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7417500052547882043L;

    private byte[] bytes;

    String fileName;
    String contentType;
    String fieldName;
    boolean isEmpty;
    long size;

    public MultipartImage(byte[] bytes, String fileName, String fieldName, String contentType, long size) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.size = size;
        this.isEmpty = false;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public String getFieldName() {
        return fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public void setBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = bytes;
    }

    public void setContentType(String contentType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public void setEmpty(boolean isEmpty) {
        this.isEmpty = isEmpty;
    }

    public void setSize(long size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return contentType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return isEmpty;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBytes() throws IOException {
        return bytes;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void transferTo(File dest) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getOriginalFilename() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return fileName;
    }

}
```

I hope this can help other people.